# Dapper dynamic params not working inside SQL WITH clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, dapper

I have to execute the following SQL query from C# using Dapper:

```
var sqlQuery = @"
  ;WITH CalculatedData AS 
  (
      SELECT
          b.Guid1C AS guid,
          b.Name AS name,
          SUM(ct.TotalSold) AS total_Sold,
          SUM(ct.TotalIncome) as total_Income 
        ,SUM(ct.SelfCost) as self_Cost
        ,SUM(ct.TotalProfit) as total_Profit 
        ,CASE WHEN (SUM(ct.TotalProfit) > 0 AND SUM(ct.TotalIncome) > 0) THEN (SUM(ct.TotalProfit) / SUM(ct.TotalIncome) * 100) ELSE 0 END as gross_Profit_Margin 
    from CalculatedTransactions ct with(nolock)
    inner join 
        Brands b with(nolock) on ct.BrandGuid = b.Guid1C 
    where ct.TransactionDate >= @fromDate and ct.TransactionDate <= @toDate 
    group by b.Guid1C, b.Name
  )
                                                                 
   SELECT total_count = count(1) OVER(), full_total_icome = SUM(total_Income) OVER(), *
   FROM CalculatedData WHERE 1=1 
   ORDER BY name ASC 
   OFFSET @skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY";
```

I'm passing dynamic params the following way:

```
var @params = new DynamicParameters();
@params.Add("fromDate", from);
@params.Add("toDate", to);
@params.Add("skip", skip);
@params.Add("take", take);

var result = await connection.QueryAsync(sqlQuery, @params);
```

The problem is that the query runs time out only from C# program.

1. If I print the query and run in SSMS, it works
2. If I comment out `where ...` clause, it works
3. If I run the query without `;WITH` clause, it works

Any idea what might be the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to to change the query little bit, I joined different table and it works. It only fails with joined `Brands`

Comment: how quickly does it perform in SSMS? and are you using the same values in SSMS that you're using in your application code? If you are, I'm thinking "parameter sniffing" or "obscure SET options" (usually the first) - but I'd like to get a bit of context first before trying to explain that

Comment: and importantly: are you running the two comparisons on the same database, with the same data? if one has 10 rows, and one as 100,000: all bets are off! you might also try `set statistics io on` in the SSMS view, to see how much work the database is doing

Comment: in SSMS it performs in 0 sec

Comment: On the exact same database and data? And: is it using SQL variables? (probably some `declare` at the top of the batch)

Comment: Correct, in SSMS I'm declaring `@fromDate`, `@toDate`, `@skip`, `@take` params using declare keyword

Comment: It fails even if I change from `where ct.TransactionDate >= @fromDate and ct.TransactionDate <= @toDate ` to `where ct.TransactionDate >= '2023.09.01' and ct.TransactionDate <= '2023.09.30' `

Comment: Tricky to investigate from here; you could *try* adding optimize-for-unknown to the select; random question: are you using any calculated+persisted+indexed columns in these tables? And have you checked that this isn't a locking issue?

Comment: Try adding option(recompile) to the end of the select and see if anything changes

Answer (score -2):

The issue you’re experiencing might be related to the `CommandTimeout` setting  in Dapper
watch it https://code-maze.com/dotnet-handling-commandtimeout-with-dapper/

Comment: No it's something different